# How to consume messages from the beginning to a particular offset

Tags: go, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, sarama

I have the map between partitions number and offsets number of a given topic in kafka. I would like to consume all messages starting from the beginning to those particular partition/offset mapping using golang. In a nutshell I would like to know whether it is possible to consume messages in kafka from the beginning to a particular offset.

I would like to know whether there are built-in tools or libraries that can help me do before I start implementing something.

Comment: https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go#reader- ?

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-go/index.html#Consumer.Seek ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer because I am like 99.9% convinced that this is correct - you cannot specify the end offset on the Consumer. The Consumer API supports OOTB:

1. Start at the beginning.
2. Start at any arbitrary position.
3. Start at the end.

Note that there's no option for specifying ranges but you can easily do that yourself: simply start at the beginning and stop when you have read whatever number of messages you need (e.g. your final offset).

See the section `Controlling Consumer Position` in [the Official API](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)